# ArcGIS Online fails to add zipped File Geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-online, file-geodatabase

I couldn’t figure out why The ArcGIS Online fails to add a zipped “file geodatabase”, and gives the following message:

> Invalid name ‘xxx.gdb’ found in input publish parameters

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename you Communities.gdb.zip into Communities.zip.

I tested it with Communities.gdb.zip, got same error. Without .gdb it works fine

Comment: Yes it worked fine, but don't you think that its a weird behavior and esri should do something about it.