# ZIP and import to ArcGIS online a personal geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-online, personal-geodatabase

This may sound dumb, but how do you zip a personal geodatabase in order to import it to ArcGIS online?

Are there other ways to import the geodatabase, different from the one below?

[ArcGIS Online fails to add zipped File Geodatabase?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/161978/the-arcgis-online-fails-to-add-a-zipped-file-geodatabase)

There is the "share as" option in ArcMap 10.1 but it's been 2 hours since it's packaging the map... it's a small and simple map.

Answer (score 3):

Look at this, maybe it helps you:
[Publish from ArcMap](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/publish-features.htm)
[Publish a service](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/get-started/windows/tutorial-publishing-a-map-service.htm)
.(It refers to geodatabase) If you have published geodatabase try add :Customize>>Toolbars>>Distributed geodatabase. On distributed database toolbar  click "extract data" and "browse" to directory where you have saved your geodatabase >>and select "post data extraction options". Maybe now you will can use your shared data in new geodatabase.

Answer (score 1):

I would try using Windows Explorer to zip the folder named *.gdb which is your File Geodatabase.

The Q&A you linked to suggests you need to take care with the name that results.

Be aware that a Personal Geodatabase (*.mdb) is not the same as a File Geodatabase.

Comment: so.. personal geodatabases can't be imported?

Comment: The documentation in the other answer suggests not.  The contents if a Personal Geodatabase are easily copied into an empty File Geodatabase.

Comment: I don't know why I chose a personal geodatabase in the first place. A File Geodatabase makes my life much easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue and found that by first 'Compacting' the file gdb in Arc Catalog (right click file GDB - select administration - select compact geodatabase), it allowed me in Windows Explorer to then right click the GDB file and "Send to.." "Compressed (Zipped) folder", while before it gave me some reader error. This ultimately allowed me to upload to AGOL as a file Geodatabase by using the "add item" "From my computer" from the "Content" tab functions.